# Go through for loop specific number of times like range() in python

Tags: java, python, for-loop

I finally got around to learning java after continuously bashing it as a python elitist lol.
All jokes aside, I'm looking forward to playing with java and already having some fun with it.

I couldn't seem to find a simple solution for my problem. Basically, I want to make a for loop that will repeat itself a specific amount of times similar to this as in python:

```
for i in range(10):
    Print("You win")
```

but for java of course.

I tried the following after some digging on the internet:

```
for (int i : new Range(10)) {
    System.out.println("You win");
}
```

The following code gave me an error saying:

```
Range cannot be resolved to a type
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean something like this? `for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {//do something}`

Comment: I think i get the idea of that, but it gives me the following error: i cannot be resolved to a variable

would i just make it =0 before the for loop?

Comment: yep it works now, great thanks mate. i will remember this as i continue with my java endeavour lol

Comment: It’s the fundamental C loop construct: (initialise;test;update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop would do the trick:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
System.out.println("you win");
}
```